# How to handle false warning "Condition is always true", as it's actually controlled by macro

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clion

I use CLion to write C++ programs. One file has

```
#ifdef USE_BAKER_READ_BARRIER
static constexpr bool kUseBakerReadBarrier = true;
#else
static constexpr bool kUseBakerReadBarrier = false;
#endif
```

and other files use `kUseBakerReadBarrier`.

CLion always complains about the usage of `kUseBakerReadBarrier`, saying the condition is always true.

[image]

Admittedly, the const is true under the current setting. But I will sometimes compile the project without compiler option `-DUSE_BAKER_READ_BARRIER`, then the branch of kUseBakerReadBarrier==false kicks in.

These kinds of false warnings add many yellow eyesores to a file and makes it hard for me to spot real warnings.

What's the best way to handle these "false always-true" warnings?

I don't want to suppress all "Simplifiable Statements" warnings, as I would like IDE to warn me like

```
bool a=true;
if(a)
   ...
```

I'm open to know the behavior/solution in other IDE, preferably Visual Studio as well.

Comment: I'm not familiar with CLion, but this is more of a compiler question than an IDE question.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: Some compilers that provide that warning will squelch the warning if you double-up the parens, `if ((kUseBakerReadBarrier))`

Comment: @DavidGrayson, CLion is using clangd-based code analysis.

Comment: Would it work to do  `if constexpr (kUseBakerReadBarrier) {`  instead?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm not using C++17. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Eljay it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Why have `kUseBakerReadBarrier` at all? Since `kUseBakerReadBarrier` is effectively `const` and can't be modified at runtime, you could just use `#ifdef USE_BAKER_READ_BARRIER` in place of `if (kUseBakerReadBarrier)` and then you wouldn't get the warnings anymore.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I completely agree. What I'm working on is Android OS source code, Google didn't reply my question.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it's doable in general; analyzing exponentially growing amount of conditional compilation of C++ which is already hard, would take an unreasonable amount of programmer's and CPU time.

You can silence a particular line with a `#pragma`, though. CLion's inspections usually even offer to do it for you as one of the the fixup variants.